# DB2 relocate with .dbf file on DB2 v. 10.5 LUW

Tags: database, db2, dbf

Hi I have a DB2 database at

```
 /db2/ins/data/ins/dbtest
```

but it origin is

```
/db2/oldins/data/oldins/dbtest1
```

I copied the files to the folders as needed.

My relocate.cfg look like:

```
DB_NAME=dbtest1,dbtest 
DB_PATH=/db2/oldins/data/dbtest1/metalog/,/db2/ins/data/ins/dbtest/metalog
INSTANCE=oldins,ins
STORAGE_PATH=/db2/oldins/data/dbtest1/data/,/db2/ins/data/ins/dbtest/data/
LOG_DIR=/db2/oldins/data/dbtest1/metalog/oldins/NODE0000/SQL00001/LOGSTREAM0000/,/db2/ins/data/ins/dbtest/metalog/NODE0000/SQL00001/
LOGARCHMETH1=DISK:/db2/backup/ins/dbtest/archivlogfiles/
```

I get this error:

```
 DBT1006N  The "/db2/oldins/data/dbtest1/data/dbtest1_TS.dbf/SQLTAG.NAM" file or device could not be opened.
```

The system is DB2 v. 10.5 LUW.

The file does exist and the priviledges are correct.

How do I add this to the relocate.cfg file or what do I need to do?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: "_The file does exist and the priviledges are correct._" -- what do you think are the correct privileges?

Comment: The db2diag.log may give more detail. Not only permissions on the file, but both the ownership and ownership/permissions of the path may be relevant, that's what may be shown in the db2diag.log

Comment: What's the output of the following command? `su - dbtest -c "ls -la /db2/oldins/data/dbtest1/data/dbtest1_TS.dbf/SQLTAG.NAM"`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of simple test case how to use db2relocatedb.

**[Db2] Simple test case shell script for db2relocatedb command**
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/1099185

It has topic about:
- db2relocatedb for changing container path

And it tells that we need to change 'path' by 'mv' command before run db2relocatedb command as below:

```
# mv storage path manually and run db2relocatedb with relocate.cfg file
mv /home/db2inst1/db/stor1 /home/db2inst1/db/new1
mv /home/db2inst1/db/stor2 /home/db2inst1/db/new2
db2relocatedb -f relocate.cfg
```

It is recommended to review it.

Hope this helps.